# Strip HTML Tags Whilst Ignoring Greater than Less than Values <>?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to strip HTML tags out of a string using a function. Everything is working well until I try to handle legitimate < > values. I've used this code to loop through the input HTML and find the character followed by 0-9 and returned the value to the output string.

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0
DECLARE @inputstring VARCHAR(50) = 'This is text <50'
DECLARE @fix VARCHAR(2)

WHILE @i <= 9
BEGIN
    SET @fix = '<'+CAST(@i AS VARCHAR)
    IF @inputstring LIKE '%' + @fix + '%'
             SET @inputstring=replace(@inputstring,'<'+CAST(@i AS VARCHAR),'[['+CAST(@i        AS VARCHAR))
    SET @fix = '>'+CAST(@i AS VARCHAR)
        IF @inputstring NOT LIKE '%'+'SPAN' + @fix + '%' AND @inputstring NOT LIKE '%'+'LI' + @fix + '%'
             SET @inputstring=replace(@inputstring,'>'+CAST(@i AS VARCHAR),']]'+CAST(@i AS VARCHAR))
     PRINT @inputstring
SET @i=@i+1
END
```

The problem arises when I have a legitimate tag followed by a number e.g. `<SPAN>50<SPAN>`
In this case, the function can't find the closing tag and truncates the returned string. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`? Or HTML encode the whole string?

Comment: What happens when I have a legitimate tag i.e. <SPAN>4200</SPAN>?

Comment: What are your legitimate tags?

Comment: So I know what can be passed into the input string as my user input richtextbox in the app dictates a certain format without inline style. <SPAN>,<LI>,<UL>,<P> and that's about it...

Comment: You have badly formed HTML (`<` should always be escaped) - I'm not sure trying to fix it in T-SQL is using the right tool for the job. Is there no opportunity to fix this data before it hits the database?

Comment: @Damien, the HTML is parsed from an rtf richtextbox in a c# WPF app. I know which tags can slip through to the db and which can't as the user input is formatted on save. Unfortunately the <SPAN> tags are a result of the HTML parser I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

I may be over simplifying this but could this work?

```
DECLARE @inputstring VARCHAR(50) = 'This is text <50'
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@inputstring, '<SPAN>', ''), '</SPAN>', ''), '<LI>', ''), '</LI>', ''), '<UL>', ''), '</UL>', ''), '<P>', ''), '</P>', ''), '<', '[['), '>', ']]')
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @Gouri. Updated the question with my solution assuming that a &lt or &gt only appear after <SPAN> or <LI> tags. I know this only because I can determine what tags are coming into the input string.